# How to change CURSOR to busy and prevent user clicking

Tags: windows, javafx, combobox

I have three COMBO BOXES in my window. It is a family tree application I am developing using JavaFX and SQLIte. Each person has Father, Mother and Spouse info which can be selected from ComboBoxes. ComboBoxes are loaded with data from database.

It takes a while to load these three combo boxes. Actually different delays for different combo boxes.

If I click on a combo box while it is not ready or another combo box is not ready, the screen turns white until the other combo box is ready.

I want to prevent user input on entire window from Mouse, Keyboard and Buttons until entire window is ready to accept user's input. Until then I want change the cursor to something like STOP.

How to do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Hornigold

Comment: Why don't you disable the `ComboBox`es until they are ready to use?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi  kleopatra, Can I send the whole project. It is not huge. I can ZIP the entire directory from Eclipse workspace and send it across. But the problem is not that, you have to navigate to this window after 4 or 5 clicks to view the popup window, where the three combo boxes are there. Alternatively, I can show the Window only after all the initialize routines complete. Is that possible ?

Comment: Hi Sunflame, how do I know that the data from observable list is loaded in my comboboxes. I first fetch the data from database into Collections. Then I say , ComboBox.SetItems(Collection);

Comment: Arthur read first that @kleopatra linked. You should not send us the whole project but provide us enough information about the problem, for example, some code snippets or sreenshots.

Comment: They are sequential in my function,
loadFathers();
loadMothers();
loadSpouses();
Will they be executed sequentially or parallel by JavaFX? As you suggested, I can Enable the ComboBoxes at the end of loadSpouses(), if these happen in sequence.  Thanks for suggestion, anyway.

Comment: I think you should load your data in a different thread so your app doesn't hang (screen turn white) or something then update the UI using `Platform.runLater()`
and you can disable the root pane of the scene so the user can't click anything

Answer (score 1):

Run a `Task<ObservableList<SomeType>>` (or a `Task` returning some object containing more than a single list) on a seperate `Thread`. Before starting the thread you disable the root and set the cursor for the scene and when the task finishes you initialize the GUI with the results and reenable the scene again:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button loadButton = new Button("load");
    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    VBox root = new VBox(combo, loadButton);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    loadButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
        root.setDisable(true);

        // save old cursor to restore after finishing the task
        final Cursor oldCursor = root.getScene().getCursor();
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

        Task<ObservableList<String>> task = new Task<ObservableList<String>>() {

            @Override
            protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
                ObservableList<String> result = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    result.add(Integer.toString(i));
                }
                // simulate delay
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return result;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            // use results of task in the GUI
            combo.setItems(task.getValue());

            // restore cursor and reenable scene
            root.setDisable(false);
            scene.setCursor(oldCursor);
        });
        task.setOnFailed(e -> {
            // todo: handle exception in Task.call
        });
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian, since I don't have a load button, I am going to try this code embedded and inline. Will let you know.

Comment: Dear Fabian, This is the place where there is an issue.